# How To Set ImageView on left and Textview on Right?

Tags: textview, imageview

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpLU2.jpg
I want to do something like this in Android Studio I tried a lot but I can't made it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Ahmet. Please post your code and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I m not on the PC now. I tried put them together in a linear and constrain layouts but didn't work.